# Do I have to create all UI elements myself when using a custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm following [this](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) tutorial for creating a custom UITableViewCell, and in the object returned from from `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ID"]`, all of its UILabels and etc. are `nil`. This tutorial doesn't say anything about creating them myself, and I would expect I wouldn't need to, judging by the way the rest of iOS works, but I don't know why they aren't being created automatically. For example, here `cell.lightName` is `nil`, even though it is hooked up to the label that exits in the custom view in IB.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *dataCellIdentifier = @"Data Cell";
    AnalysisHistoryTableViewCell *cell = (AnalysisHistoryTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:dataCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];    
    self.selectedAnalysis = self.analysisResults[indexPath.row];
    cell.lightNameLabel.text = self.selectedAnalysis.lightName;
    return cell;
}
```

What am I doing wrong thats causing my `UILabel`s to not exist?

Comment: I am assuming that in your AnalysisHistoryTableViewCell you have synthesized the property that is connected to the UILabel in your cell.

Comment: Have you registered the nib with the table view (`registerNib:`)?

Comment: Are you using a Xib or a storyboard? Where are you declaring the label? Did you synthesize the label or not?

Comment: I had not synthesized the label. I usually just refer to it using `self`. I tried that though, and it didn't help.

Comment: @sooper I hadn't. Doing this fixed the problem, though. I wonder why that wan't mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: Where do you allocate the cell? Check cell==nil

Comment: @Drew Glad it worked, I posted a full answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a custom cell you'll need to register the nib first:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"AnalysisHistoryTableViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Data Cell"];
}
```

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    AnalysisHistoryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Data Cell"];

    //etc

    return cell;
}
```